# Average in RxJava

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

I am trying to make a system resource monitor using Rx. I use a thread for observable which returns the CPU Usage every 1000 milliseconds. Now I want my subscriber to find the average of the CPU usage every 10 seconds.

```
    public class seperate {
    private ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executorPool;
    public void test()
   {

    Observable<Double> myObservable = Observable.create(
            new Observable.OnSubscribe<Double>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Subscriber<? super Double> sub) {
                    executorPool = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(9);
                    int timeout1 = 10;
                    TimerTask timeoutTimertask1=new MyTimerTasks(sub);
                    executorPool.scheduleAtFixedRate(timeoutTimertask1,timeout1, timeout1,
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                    // This returns the cpu usage every 10ms.                      

                }
            }
        );
    Subscriber<Double> mySubscriber = new Subscriber<Double>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(Double s) { System.out.println(s); }

        @Override
        public void onCompleted() { }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) { }
    };
    myObservable.subscribe(mySubscriber);

}
```

}

Comment: question? Do you have problem with finding CPU stats or rx api?

Comment: No I have found that, and my observable is now streaming the CPU Usage, I just need to break it in blocks of 10 and find average.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [buffer](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/buffer.html) or [window](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/window.html) to divide source emission into groups of items, then calculate [average](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/average.html) on each group.

Avarage is a part of rxjava-math library.

Moreover you can simplify your code using [interval](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/interval.html).

Below is example using window and interval:

```
Observable myObservable = Observable.interval(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
           .map(new Func1<Long, Double>() {                    
                @Override
                public Double call(Long aLong) {
                    Double d = 100.;//calculate CPU usage                             
                    return d;
                }
            })
            .window(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .flatMap(new Func1<Observable<Double>, Observable<Double>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<Double> call(Observable<Double> windowObservable) {
                    return MathObservable.averageDouble(windowObservable);
                }
            });
```

Comment: The above code doesn't run. I did a debugging and found that the program never enters _italic_  public Observable<Double> call()

Comment: Did you subscribe to Observable?

Comment: It can be due to 2 reasons : You did not subscribe to Observable or your program (main block) exits immediately. In your example, where you used Thread pool, the non daemon threads created by pool, prevent process from exiting,whereas in my case you have to do it explicit - eg. using Thread.sleep(100000)

Comment: I have subscribed in the following way:                                                              Subscriber<Observable<Double>> mySubscriber = new Subscriber<Observable<Double>>() {
     
     public void onNext(Observable<Double> s) { System.out.println(s); }

     
     public void onCompleted() { }

    
     public void onError(Throwable e) { }
 };
 myObservable.subscribe(mySubscriber);

Comment: Looks ok, try adding Thread.sleep(100000)  after myObservable.subscribe

Answer (score 1):

Use MathObservable like so:

```
MathObservable.averageLong(longsObservable).subscribe(average -> Timber.d("average:%d", average));
```

More info can be found here:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Mathematical-and-Aggregate-Operators

Source Code:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaMath